# React Native, expo go app is very buggy and takes long to render

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, mobile, expo

I am using React Native and DynamoDB to create an app and testing on Expo Go. My app is essentially trying to render a bunch of elements (with around 15 attributes -- lat, lon, etc.) that I fetch from the database on google maps api. I have approximately 200 elements that I am storing in redux that I want to display, but it is being very buggy and slow. I will be scaling the app to many more elements, so this is a huge performance issue. Any advice on how to go about this?

I tried reducing the number of elements, and then it was working fine, but that doesn't address the issue. Is it possible that Expo Go is for very lightweight apps? But even then, 200 elements is not a lot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.